# CakePHP action returning array

Tags: php, cakephp

In my controller called, lets say, TestController I have an action (method) called test():

```
public function test() {
    $this->autoRender = false; // becouse I need action with no view (I just need it to return array for antoher action)

    return array();
}
```

And when I call this method from index action in my controller it breakes my app (nothing appear when I try to view my test/index view.

Is there any way to make method in controller that returns array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved this. I just deleted autorender part

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use $ this-> layout=false; insted of $ this-> autorender=false;  that's why its not working